# Can Kafka Stream sub tasks delete from state store simultaneously

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have one question w.r.t kafka-stream state stores getAll() and delete().
My topology is simple it has one source topic, one processor node and sink topic. I need to maintain state of the stream so I'm using KeyValue based state store.
The processor node reads saves the state in KVStore(rocksdb) in process() and then punctuator scheduled at certain time performs getAll() from the state store, performs certain complex business logic and once done deletes the retrieved entries/keys from stateStore.

Now, my question is if there are multiple sub-tasks(stream threads) running this logic of doing getAll from stateStore and then delete. Is it possible that each of these different sub-tasks(threads) end up getting all the keys and then each of them attempting delete ?

Or is in other words if the `KeyValueIterator<K, V> all()` returns all the keys across all the partitions of the stateStore OR only the shard'ed partition dedicated to that sub-task(thread).

Thanks,